# Ubuntu systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result ‘dependency’

Tags: docker

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 to run a dockerized NextCloud installation. Usually, I just need to run

```
$ docker-compose pull
$ docker-compose up -d
```

to update my containers but now I ran into the following error:

```
# service docker status

● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: inactive (dead)

TriggeredBy: **●** docker.socket

Docs: https://docs.docker.com

Jun 06 12:19:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: **Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.**

Jun 06 12:19:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: **docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.**

Jun 06 12:20:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: **Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.**

Jun 06 12:20:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: **docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.**

Jun 06 12:22:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: **Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.**

Jun 06 12:22:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: **docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.**

Jun 06 12:29:03 ubuntu systemd[1]: **Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.**

Jun 06 12:29:03 ubuntu systemd[1]: **docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.**

Jun 06 12:33:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: **Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.**

Jun 06 12:33:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: **docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.**
```

I tried to re-install docker but that did not resolve the problem. When running

```
apt-get install docker-ce
```

I obtain the above mentioned error.

Any idea how to continue?

Comment: Please edit the post and show us the content of `/etc/docker/daemons.json` and `$HOME/.docker/config.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The content of /etc/docker/daemons.json is: {
    "graph": "/data/docker"
}      I can't find a file ./docker/config.json, though

Comment: What's the content of `/data/docker`?

Comment: The content of /data/docker are directories: builder  buildkit  containers  image  network  overlay2  plugins  runtimes  swarm  tmp  trust  volumes

Answer (score 2):

For future viewers.
I had the same problem.

Solution for me:

```
groupadd docker
systemctl start docker.socket
```

It seems I accidentally deleted the docker group.
This led to docker.socket not starting which in turn is a dependency of docker.service, hence the not so helpful error you recieved.

Comment: This was the best answer for me, my system was missing the docker group and couldn't run

Answer (score 0):

Related to last comment, try this

```
mv /data/docker /data/docker.old
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Please tell me if it worked...

Comment: OK, I have moved the data folder as you suggested. However, it does not start: systemctl start docker
A dependency job for docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
root@ubuntu:~# journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit containerd.service has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 199572.
Jun 06 15:25:46 ubuntu containerd[32057]: time="2021-06-06T15:25:46.443159173Z" level=info msg="starting containerd" revisi>

Comment: ...Jun 06 15:25:46 ubuntu containerd[32057]: panic: invalid freelist page: 7, page type is leaf

Comment: Jun 06 15:25:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start containerd container runtime.
-- Subject: A start job for unit containerd.service has failed

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was not able to resolve the error and have setup a new server. Thank you anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try starting dockerd as below "/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://"
you can see the error why docker is not starting.